# How to get the avro schema from StructType

Tags: spark-avro

I have a dataFrame

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = getSparkInstance().createDataFrame(newRDD, struct);
```

`dataset.schema()` is returning me a StructType.

But I want the actual schema to store in `sample.avsc` file

Basically I want to convert StructType to Avro Schema file (.avsc).

any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is the work around that will solve my problem.
Here I am saving the .avro file and getting the schema back from it.

```
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("outputPath");

            File files = new File("outputPath");
            String[] children = files.list();

            String filename="";
            for(String file : children) {
                if (file.contains("SUCCESS")) {

                }else {
                    filename=file;
                    if(file.contains(".crc")) {
                        filename= file.replaceAll(".crc", "");
                        if(filename.startsWith(".")) {
                            filename=filename.substring(1);

                        }
                        while(!new File("outputPath/"+filename).exists()) {
                            System.out.println("outputPath/"+filename);
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
            System.out.println(files.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+filename);
            DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
            DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new File("outputPath/"+filename), datumReader);
            Schema schema = dataFileReader.getSchema();
            System.out.println(schema.toString());
```